# DataMember property "Type" cannot be found on the DataSource

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have create the following class for XML deserialization:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class ProgrammingConfiguration
{
    private uint versionField;
    private byte[] eLFImageField;
    private PreferenceType[] preferencesField;
    private ProgrammingConfigurationProtectFlashAfterProgramming   protectFlashAfterProgrammingField;

    //XML version
    public uint Version
    {
        get { return this.versionField; }
        set { this.versionField = value; }
    }

    //ELF image
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "base64Binary")]
    public byte[] ELFImage
    {
        get { return this.eLFImageField; }
        set { this.eLFImageField = value; }
    }

    //Preference
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Preference", IsNullable = false)]
    public PreferenceType[] Preferences
    {
        get { return this.preferencesField; }
        set { this.preferencesField = value; }
    }

    //Protect flash after programming
    public ProgrammingConfigurationProtectFlashAfterProgramming ProtectFlashAfterProgramming
    {
        get { return this.protectFlashAfterProgrammingField; }
        set { this.protectFlashAfterProgrammingField = value; }
    }
}

//Preference Type
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class PreferenceType
{
    private string tagField;
    private PreferenceTypePrecedence precedenceField;
    private ValueType valueField;

    public string Tag
    {
        get { return this.tagField; }
        set { this.tagField = value; }
    }

    public PreferenceTypePrecedence Precedence
    {
        get { return this.precedenceField; }
        set { this.precedenceField = value; }
    }

    public ValueType Value
    {
        get { return this.valueField; }
        set { this.valueField = value; }
    }
}

//Precedence Type
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public enum PreferenceTypePrecedence
{
    XML,
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Target,XML")]
    TargetXML,
    Target,
}

//Value Type
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class ValueType
{
    private string lengthField;
    private object itemField;
    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
    public string Length
    {
        get { return this.lengthField; }
        set { this.lengthField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AutoIncrement", typeof(ValueTypeAutoIncrement))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("HexBinary", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Integer", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("String", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item
    {
        get { return this.itemField; }
        set { this.itemField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
    {
        get { return this.itemElementNameField; }
        set { this.itemElementNameField = value; }
    }
}

//Autoincrement data
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ValueTypeAutoIncrement
{
    private string minimumField;
    private string maximumField;
    private ValueTypeAutoIncrementOverflowBehaviour overflowBehaviourField;

    public string Minimum
    {
        get { return this.minimumField; }
        set { this.minimumField = value; }
    }

    public string Maximum
    {
        get { return this.maximumField; }
        set { this.maximumField = value; }
    }

    public ValueTypeAutoIncrementOverflowBehaviour OverflowBehaviour
    {
        get { return this.overflowBehaviourField; }
        set { this.overflowBehaviourField = value; }
    }
}

//Overflow behaviour
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public enum ValueTypeAutoIncrementOverflowBehaviour
{
    Wrap,
    Exception,
}

//Data type
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType
{
    AutoIncrement,
    HexBinary,
    Integer,
    String,
}

//ProtectFlashAfterProgramming
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public enum ProgrammingConfigurationProtectFlashAfterProgramming
{
    True,
    False,
}
```

I want to create 2 binding source, one for datagridview and one for textbox.  I have tried the following:

```
        ProgrammingConfiguration pc = new ProgrammingConfiguration();

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProgrammingConfiguration));

        //Reading the XML document requires a FileStream.            
        Stream reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

        //Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
        pc = (ProgrammingConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        reader.Close();

        bindingsource.DataSource = pc;
        bindingsource.DataMember = "Preferences";


        bsV.DataSource = bindingsource;
        bsV.DataMember = "ItemElementName";
```

The program failed to run at the line bsV.DataMember = "ItemElementName".   Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
bindingsource.DataSource = pc;
```

to:

```
bindingsource.DataSource = new List { pc };
```

i dont know why but PropertyManager doesnt like chaining properties, however CurrencyManager does. using an IEnumerable will fool and force the BindingContext create CurrencyManager instead of PropertyManager which is for binding single object. the issue isnt related to BindingSource you could set the DataSource property of the grid to the list and DataMember to the Preferences instead.

you dont have to use BindingSource to bind to the textbox either.

simply use:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add(list, "Preferences.ItemElementName");
```

as for Value.Maximum use on of the:

```
textBoxMaximum.DataBindings.Add(list, Preferences.Value.Maximum);
textBoxMaximum.DataBindings.Add(bindingSource, Value.Maximum);
```