# Get children of a data row

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have been trying to display all children of a certain selected parent from a dataGrid. I used this tutorial as a guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y8c0cxey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but with no luck. Here is my code:

```
private void getData()
{
      SqlDataAdapter parentDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Airline", connection);
      parentDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Airline");
      SqlDataAdapter childDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Plane", connection);
      childDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Plane");

      DataColumn parentColumn = ds.Tables["Airline"].Columns["airline_id"];
      DataColumn childColumn = ds.Tables["Plane"].Columns["airline_id"];

      relation = new DataRelation("pln_air", parentColumn, childColumn);
      ds.Relations.Add(relation);

      parentBindingSource.DataSource = ds;
      parentBindingSource.DataMember = "Airline";
      childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
      childBindingSource.DataMember = "Plane";   
}
```

Cell Content Click event of datagridview is as under:

```
private void dg_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    parentDataGridView.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
    childDataGridView.DataSource = childBindingSource;
    getData();            
}
```

My problem is that when I run it and I click on a cell I get an error: `DataMember property 'Plane' cannot be found on the DataSource.`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677156/datamember-property-type-cannot-be-found-on-the-datasource

Comment: `getData()` is called after you bind data sources. Check in `dg_CellContentClick` event

Comment: So when should I call it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the name of the DataRelation as the DataMember for the child BindingSource, not the name of the child DataTable.

Comment: I have changed "childBindingSource.DataMember = "pln_air" " but now when I click on a cell I get "A Relation named 'pln_air' already belongs to this DataSet."

Comment: That sounds rather like you are trying to add the DataRelation twice.